# Does IronPython use Python 2 or Python 3?

Tags: ironpython, ironpython-studio

I am new to IronPyton, but would like to start using it.  From the IronPython website, I see that the current version of IronPyton is 2.7.8  My understanding is that this version is independent of the official Python version.

Which version of Python (2 or 3) does IronPyton use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From their [website](https://ironpython.net/documentation/):

> Since IronPython is a implementation of Python 2.7 [...]

Note that there is also [IronPython 3](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3), which is not yet ready for production and will support Python 3.